# Add custom node content to cache

Tags: nodes, caching

I have added a few custom nodes to my website via the admin CMS. I wanted to know if I would have to explicitly add them to cache or if the nose_save or one of the internal drupal methods would add it to cache? I am using memcache for my caching purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, Drupal caches pages for *anonymous* users. This is true for all nodes. You can turn this, together with some other caching settings, on and off at admin/config/development/performance

If memcache handles the data that otherwise goes into cache_page, then you will benefit from memcache in returning nodes.